# actionbar NullPointerException with NewsReader Demo project

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I tried using [NewsReader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/training/multiscreen/newsreader) to derive code for something that I'm working on and I ran into an issue with the action bar. So I decided to just recreate the NewsReader code exactly (with reasonable edits for package names and such) and I still ran into the same issue.

I hit an error with this invoke:

```
 setUpActionBar(mIsDualPane, catIndex);
```

Because of this line:

```
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

**Full method**:

```
public void setUpActionBar(boolean showTabs, int selTab) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
        // No action bar for you!
        // But do not despair. In this case the layout includes a bar across the
        // top that looks and feels like an action bar, but is made up of regular views.
        return;
    }
    android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    // Set up a CompatActionBarNavHandler to deliver us the Action Bar nagivation events
    CompatActionBarNavHandler handler = new CompatActionBarNavHandler(this);
    if (showTabs) {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < CATEGORIES.length; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(CATEGORIES[i]).setTabListener(handler));
        }
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(selTab);
    }
    else {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        SpinnerAdapter adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.actionbar_list_item,
                CATEGORIES);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adap, handler);
    }
    // Show logo instead of icon+title.
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
}
```

It seems some of the actionBar stuff is deprecated as well so that might be part of the problem. How can I fix/update this?

**Stack Trace:**

```
06-16 09:24:21.211 24376-24376/com.anothergamedesigner.newsreader E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.anothergamedesigner.newsreader, PID: 24376
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anothergamedesigner.newsreader/com.anothergamedesigner.newsreader.NewsReaderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.anothergamedesigner.newsreader.NewsReaderActivity.setUpActionBar(NewsReaderActivity.java:119)
    at com.anothergamedesigner.newsreader.NewsReaderActivity.onCreate(NewsReaderActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Looks like you used an AppCompatActivity that has a theme with no Toolbar.

Comment: @cricket_007 This demo project extends FragmentActivity, not AppCompatActivity. I think what I'm discovering is this code is old and deprecated with later SDKs. Do you think I can change the extends to AppCompatActivity and then I should rewrite the ActionBar or?

Comment: @user3453550 You should extend AppComaptActivity as it extends FragmentActivity by default.  If it is still throwing an error, change your code as directed in my answer.

Comment: Look at the `styles.xml` file. `android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` is used, so the `getActionBar()` method shouldn't be returning anything since there is no ActionBar to get. `AppCompatActivity` would have the same problem

Comment: I've updated my answer with the necessary changes to the styles and manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

to

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

EDIT:

You also need to edit your styles.xml and your AndroidManifest.xml.

In your styles.xml, change

```
<style name="NewsReaderStyle" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

to

```
<style name="NewsReaderStyle" parent="android:Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

And in your AndroidManifest.xml, change

```
android:theme="@style/NewsReaderStyle_NoActionBar"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/NewsReaderStyle"
```

AppCompat Styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Now add android:theme="@style/AppTheme" to your manifest.

Comment: I actually used some digging to change my styles.xml already, but I didn't change it to what you suggested. I started to run into an issue where because I am now extending AppCompatActivity, I got an error stating that I needed to use android:Theme.AppCompat.

So following some a different stackoverflow answer I changed my AndroidManifest.xml to 

            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

I don't know how correct this is though, because some say this is a cheat because it's just overriding styles.xml?

Comment: It's just using a packaged theme, so you won't be able to change it at all.  You can replace your current themes with these and then use the correct one in your manifest.  I will add the themes to my answer.